# Do the metabolisms of anorexic individuals ever recover?

Tags: nutrition, metabolism, anorexia, eating-disorder

Following my fascination with what is commonly referred to as 'metabolism,' I realized that I know a few "recovered anorexics" (please let me know if there is a better term), all of whom maintain normal weight on a normal lifestyle, and one of whom has decided to become a dietician to help others with the condition.

It occurred to me that while these individuals now eat basically normally, they also don't seem to have a propensity to gain weight above that which would be expected of others of their ages, genders and backgrounds. This would seem very odd considering some only a few months earlier had BMIs below 15, eating under 500 calories a day.

The question is, therefore:

**Do metabolisms, or more specifically the normal ability to process "normal" amounts of food for energy while maintaining "normal" weight, of individuals with anorexia nervosa recover, and in what way?**

Comment: For the "& in what way" part of the question, are you asking for the biological mechanisms behind changing metabolisms?  The studies I know off hand are from people who were starving due to circumstance (not anorexia), but I think it will be generalizable.  I'm going to start a lit review to be sure, but if the case is similar to say, a starving child, then the answer will be yes, though if growth has been stunted the delay will often persist.

Comment: @Atl That's definitely a good part of what I'm looking for. Would you mind providing sources?

Answer (score 3):

They appear to.

In [Caloric consumption and activity levels after weight recovery in anorexia nervosa: a prolonged delay in normalization](http://health.ucsd.edu/specialties/psych/clinic-based/eatingdisorders/neurobiology/Documents/KayeIJED1986CaloricConsumptionAN.pdf), researchers looked at anorexia patients 2 to 6 weeks after what is called "refeeding", and patients 6 months after.

> Patients with anorexia nervosa, in the weeks after achieving target
>   weight and terminating refeeding, have elevated levels of activity and
>   caloric intake, compared to normal controls. In contrast, caloric intake
>   and activity in anorectics who had maintained weight for months after
>   weight recovery were similar to controls.

So they were maintaining weight at the same amount of calories that people without a history of anorexia were also maintaining their weight at.

The same was found in this study: [Resting metabolic rate and total energy expenditure in acute and weight recovered patients with anorexia nervosa and in healthy young women](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/1098-108X(199407)16:1%3C45::AID-EAT2260160104%3E3.0.CO;2-Z/abstract)

> No significant differences were found between the weight-recovered anorectic women and the healthy controls in RMR (1,330 ± 131 kcal/day [weight-recovered]; 1,419 ± 197 [controls]) and in TEE (2,602 ± 637 kcal/day [weight-recovered]; 2,596 ± 493 kcal/day [controls]).

RMR = Resting Metabolic Rate; TEE = Total Energy Expenditure

Both studies had small sample sizes though.

During recovery, patients recovering from anorexia need more calories than expected for weight gain, which is called *hypermetabolic*, but that period ends at around 4 to 6 months.

[Nutritional rehabilitation in anorexia nervosa: review of the literature and implications for treatment](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3829207/) (figure 2)